# How do I make my "volume up" more powerful in Win7?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, audio

My volume up button raises the volume by 1%. Its also not a button, it's a weird 'touch' thing which is really really terrible. If I want to lower the volume, I have to awkwardly rub it for a while. If it were to decrease by 5% or 10% it would be a lot better.

Can this be set somewhere in Windows/Keyboard settings?

I got close to a solution with Autohotkey, where I could do this:

```
a::Send {Volume_Up 5}
```

which would send the volume up command five times, 
however when I assign it to the volume key, it forms an **endless loop** since the Send command sends Volume_Up and parses it at the same time.

**Update: I ended up with this script:**

```
$Volume_Up::VolumeUp()
$Volume_Down::VolumeDown()

VolumeUp( ) {
    Send {Volume_Up 6} 
    SoundBeep, 750, 50
}
VolumeDown( ) {
    Send {Volume_Down 6} 
    SoundBeep, 750, 50 
}
```

Comment: +1 for 'awkwardly rub it for a while'  I am generally very unimpressed with the scale volume controls use where there is not nearly enough finegrain control on the low end and way too much on the high end

Comment: If you don't mind running an autohotkeyscript all the time (doesn't really consume any amount of resources) I recommend it. It takes about 10 steps up or down, and I can still change it manually if I have to.

Comment: i usually find myself more in trouble on the lower end when 0-is off 1-is midvolume 2-is quite loud and 50-just a bit louder than 2. you can't increment by decimals can you?

Comment: no but that sounds like you have a busted Sound driver. I recall having this issue in Windows 98. That is definitely not normal behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the [`$` prefix](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) to your script, it should block the script from picking up its own sent commands.